# MTBURN Ads in RecyleView Adapter

Tags: android

I haved old code:
NewsListFragment.java

```
/**
 * AppDavis SDK を初期化して、広告案件のロードを開始する
 */
private void setupSDK() {

    //　任意の View に広告案件情報を割り当てる
    InstreamAdViewBinderImpl adViewBinder = new InstreamAdViewBinderImpl(this.activityParent){
        @Override
        public View createView(ViewGroup parent, int layoutId) {
            d("createView");
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(NewsListFragment.this.activityParent).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_mtburn_ad, parent, false);
            NewsListAdapter.AdViewHolder holder = new NewsListAdapter.AdViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindAdData(View v, ADVSInstreamInfoModel adData) {
            d("createView");
            NewsListAdapter.AdViewHolder holder = (NewsListAdapter.AdViewHolder)v.getTag();
            mNewsListAdapter.setLayout();
            holder.setData(adData);
            loadAdImage(adData, holder.imageViewAdImage, null);
        }
    };

    if(adPlacer != null) {
        adPlacer.registerAdViewBinder(adViewBinder);

        // 広告読み込み開始
        adPlacer.setAdListener(listener);
        adPlacer.loadAd();
    }
}

private ADVSInstreamAdPlacerListener listener = new ADVSInstreamAdPlacerListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAdsLoaded(List<? extends ADVSInstreamInfoModel> paramList) {
        // ネイティブ広告が読み込まれたとき
        d("onAdsLoaded");
        if(mNewsListAdapter == null){
            return;
        }
        List<ADVSInstreamInfoModel> modelList = new ArrayList<ADVSInstreamInfoModel>();
        for(ADVSInstreamInfoModel adData:paramList){
            modelList.add(adData);
        }

        mNewsListAdapter.setNativeAds(modelList, mAdDataIndex);
        mNewsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdMainImageLoaded(String paramString) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        d("onAdMainImageLoaded:" + paramString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdIconImageLoaded(String paramString) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        d("onAdIconImageLoaded:" + paramString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdsLoadedFail(String paramString) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        d("onAdsLoadedFail:" + paramString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdImageLoadedFail(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        d("onAdImageLoadedFail:" + paramString1 + ":" + paramString2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(String paramString) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        d("onAdClicked:" + paramString);
    }

};
```

NewsListAdapter.java (function getView)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    JSONNewsListItem item;
    Advertisement adItem;
    ADVSInstreamInfoModel nativeAdItem;

    if (this.getNativeAdIndex(position) >= 0 ) {

        // NativeAd
        // 広告案件を表現するカスタム View を取り出して表示する
        nativeAdItem = this.getNativeAdFromListPosition(position);
        if(nativeAdItem != null){
            DebugLog.d(TAG, "MTBURN表示");
            convertView = adPlacer.placeAd(nativeAdItem, convertView, parent);
        }else{
            DebugLog.d(TAG, "広告読み込み中表示");
        }
        setBackGround(convertView,position);
        return convertView;
    }
```

}

Now I want use RecyleView Adapter, I want convert this code to RecyleView Adapter. However, I can't load layout the same the old code.

Please help me how to convert to onBindViewHolder in RecyleView Adapter.

Thank you so much.